# get the files in folder between two timestamp using windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I have a folder 'script'. People check-in the files to this folder. Every time they check-in, I need to get the those files alone and execute them. For that, current timestamp needs to be saved in some log file. so that we can get the files that are modified after the last build by comparing the current time with last execution time(which is saved in log file). Let me explain that clearly.

Folder name -- script.
there three files in this folder -- a.sql, b.sql, c.sql

---

after few hours -- two new files are created. also b.sql is modified.
totally five files -- a.sql, b.sql, c.sql, d.sql, e.sql

---

now I need to execute only those two new files and one modified file.
it should be like below
b.sql
d.sql
e.sql

---

we need to compare the current time with last execution time and get the files that are modified/created between two timestamps.

Can someone tell me how to do it using batch script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simplier approach, you might want to consider using the *Archive* bit assigned to a file. This will be set to 1/ON when a file is created or updated.

The idea is you look for files in your folder with the *Archive* bit set and then do your action before resetting it.

```
REM Process all files which have the Archive bit set.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR "C:\Dir\To\Process" /A:A /B`) DO (
    ECHO Processing File: "%%A"

    REM Do your actions here...

    REM Reset the Archive bit.
    ATTRIB -A "%%A"
)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a ton dude :) Is there any way to sort the files by timestamp? if there are multiple files, last modified\created file should come last.

Comment: @smartboy - Sure, in the `DIR` command, add this switch: `/O:D`.